Set latitute/longitude of LAS point cloud (via GeoTIFF VLRs)
I have an app that generates a LAS point cloud.
The coordinates are just relative to the center of the point cloud. No geographic location, just starting at [0,0,0].
I however also have the latitude/longitude at which the point cloud was recorded, and would like to add this information to the LAS file when writing it in my app so that tools like Cesium can automatically place the point cloud at the right location.
So I studied the LAS specification and found that I can add GeoTIFF-compatible VLRs to the LAS header.
However, no matter which keys I'm setting, the point cloud placement never seems correct.
Here is what I thought should work for the GeoKeyDirectoryTag:
GTModelTypeGeoKey (1024) = ModelTypeProjected (1)
GTRasterTypeGeoKey (1025) = RasterPixelIsPoint (2)
GeographicTypeGeoKey (2048) = GCS_WGS_84 (4326)
GeogGeodeticDatumGeoKey (2050) = Datum_WGS84 (6326)
GeogPrimeMeridianGeoKey (2051) = PM_Greenwich (8901)
GeogLinearUnitsGeoKey (2052) = Linear_Meter (9001)
GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey (2054) = Angular_Degree (9102)
GeogEllipsoidGeoKey (2056) = Ellipse_WGS_84 (7030)
ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey (3072) = user-defined (32767)
ProjectionGeoKey (3074) = user-defined (32767)
ProjCoordTransGeoKey (3075) = user-defined (32767)
ProjOriginLongGeoKey (3080) = <my longitude>
ProjOriginLatGeoKey (3081) = <my latitude>

Am I mistaken in my understanding how the LAS/GeoTIFF codes should work?
I read the specification and "cook-book", but for the precise parameters they didn't give any information.
